# Stuck in Prolog Directory

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am just getting started in prolog and have to do a project with it. My professor spent all of 10 minutes on it and then assigned us a final project with it. I am attempting to get it done but I don't understand how to switch directories. I know you're supposed to use `working_directory(oldDir,newDir)`. But I'm stuck in my oldDir and says my newDir doesn't exist. My oldDir is /Applications/ and I'm trying to get to /Documents/ but it is telling me that this doesn't exist.

Here is exactly what I tried:

```
?- working_directory(CWD,'/Documents/').
ERROR: directory `'/Documents/'' does not exist
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] '$chdir'('/Documents/')
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
?-
```

Please help! I can't do my project if I can't check anything.

Comment: I don't think that **/Documents/** is a good working directory name,try **'c:/users/<username>/Documents/'** if you use Windows. Anyway, try **working_directory(CWD, CWD).** to know the name of the current working directory.

Comment: I'm on a Mac unfortunately. And that's how I know I'm in the applications folder so I guess my real problem is I'm stuck in that folder and can't navigate out of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try 
    working_directory (CWD, 'Documents').

Comment: when I do that, I get:                                                                              ERROR: directory `'Documents'' does not exist
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] '$chdir'('Documents')
ERROR:    [8] '$syspreds':working_directory(//,'Documents') at /Applications/SWI-Prolog.app/Contents/swipl/boot/syspred.pl:1102
ERROR:    [7] <user>

Comment: In what directory are those running swipl?